# Can't use var1=$(cmd) in bash script (only in unix)

Tags: bash, variables, unix, scripting, setting

I'm trying to do this:

```
OS=$(uname -s)
```

It runs fine at the terminal, but, it throws this:

> syntax error on line x:'OS=$' unexpected

I'm using #!/bin/bash.

Comment: Works fine in a script here. Could something on the previous line in your script be causing the error?

Comment: previous lines were
#!/bin/bash

SunOS="SunOS"

Linux runs the script error-less only in UNIX I encounter this error

Comment: Make sure bash exists in your UNIX platform. `which bash`

Comment: Clean your script of pesky Windows `\r` chars with `dos2unix scriptName.sh`? Good luck.

Comment: check to make sure there are no spaces between OS=$( this should give you an error in the terminal as well though)

Comment: On Solaris (SunOS), the `/bin/sh` is an old Bourne shell and does not recognize `$(…)` notation.  If you use `sh script.sh`, the code will fail with exactly that error.  Make sure the shebang uses `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/ksh` and make sure you run the script with one of those shells and not with `sh`.

Comment: Changed bash , still the same result
Tried dos2unix
And the OS=$ are tight together

Comment: Running it with bash script.sh fixed it Thanks kind human being!

Comment: @kakaman997, since it starts with `#!/bin/bash`, just running it with `./yourscript` (after setting the +x bit) should work fine too (and is preferred, since it puts the script in control of its interpreter); it's *specifically* the use of `sh` that breaks things.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
OS="$(uname -s)"
```

I do not have a system to test this on, but I was reviewing a script I created prior, and that is how I had set up that exact variable.

Comment: This works, but quotation marks are not needed: 
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bsd-appleosx-bash-assign-variable-command-output/